# C++ Intellisense not always working in vscode

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

While in the middle of working on my app I had an odd issue and, while trying to figure  it out, I noticed right clicking anywhere on my code doesn't give me the usual options.

The below image shows what my options are for anything that I click. I should have double or more options to choose from, like opening the document I've right clicked.

The odd issue (which may or may not be related) I had before this started happening was I that I just created a new header and source file. In the source file, VSCode was complaining that it could not find the new header file that I included. I tried including it in a different file, and it *could* find it there. I'm very confused as to why two files in the same directory are getting different results when they include the same header file.

[image]

Does anyone know what happened, and how to fix it?

I have restarted VSCode multiple times, as well as my computer.

Comment: At a guess you are using the cmake plugin to configure your intellisense? intellisense wont work when you create a new file until you've added that file to your cmakelists.txt and done a build

Comment: Ah yes, I just started learning cmake so I forgot to add the new files to the cmakelists.txt. Ok, I have done that, and got a successful compile, and restarted VSCode again, yet still borked intellisense. EDIT: See my answer

Comment: I think the title might better be "VScode Intellisense not always working with C++". That names the culprit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how or why, but while editing code, my c++ extension was uninstalled.

Installing it again has resolved the issue.